# Einstein's quote vs Einstein quote

Tags: possessives

1. Einstein's quote vs 2. Einstein quote

[as in: Let me tell you Einstein's quote. It goes like this: *xyz*]

Is 1. the proper way to say this? Is 2. colloquial language?

And is it very rare to hear someone say something like "this is a quote of Einstein"?
Also, a native speaker suggested to say "a quote from Einstein", which seems to me like a safe choice.

Comment: You need some kind of "determiner" before the primary noun ***quote*** - ***the, a,*** or a possessive - ***my, his,...*** In this context, name PLUS Saxon genitive ***Einstein's*** is a determiner.

Comment: 1. No. 2. No.  Keep it simple instead:  **Einstein said "......"**

Answer (score 2):

*Einstein's quote* could mean that Einstein was quoting something from the work of another writer.

The 'proper' word is *quotation*, though *quote* is commonly used as a noun to mean words being quoted.

Your friend is right in saying that the correct expression is *a quote/quotation from Einstein.*

Comment: "A quotation from Einstein" seems to my ear to imply we are specifically quoting something from his body of work; something he wrote or recorded.   Do you also hear it that way?

Comment: @BadZen - I thought  that was the meaning that the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

#### “To quote Einstein...”

If you are introducting a quote from the person, the normal formulations are

- To quote `[person]`, “`[...]`”
- As `[person]` said, “`[...]`”
- `[person]` said: “`[...]`”

(you can use “wrote” in place of “said” if you want to emphasise that it is a  quotes from a written work, but “said” works for both).

When introducing quotes, it’s also common use “once said” or “once wrote” rather than just “said” “wrote”.

- “[once](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/once)” *adv.*: in the past.

(Note the meaning of “once” here; this has nothing to do with how many times the thing was said). Adding the word “once” makes it clear to the reader or listener that the quotation you’re about to relay is not something recent.

Some examples of these:

- To quote Cicero, “If you have a garden and a library, you have everything you need”.
- As Jane Austen wrote, “It isn’t what we say or think that defines us, but what we do.”
- Albert Einstein said: “Information is not knowledge. The only source of knowledge is experience.”
- A great philosopher once said, “Time is an illusion; lunchtime doubly so”.